# Adding Bootstrap Navbar to create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a brand new project created with `create-react-app`. I have added bootstrap:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@3
```

And I've imported it at my root `index.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Now I've added the Navbar example from the [Bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) to the top of the default `App.js` jsx and I get an unformatted mess.

I know that bootstrap is working in this file because I also added a button that is being styled properly via bootstrap. But the navbar isn't working at all.

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
          <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item active">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <button className="btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: issue can be related to that you are using v4 bootstrap example with bootstrap v3.

Comment: If you can't recreate the problem in a JSFiddle then it's more than likely something in your setup. What happens when you inspect the navbar? Is the html even showing up? Create-react-app uses service workers for caching, so you may need to restart your server and do a hard refresh to see your changes.

Comment: @bennygenel This is the correct answer. As soon as I updated my npm package to the latest (bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6) it worked. If you'd like to reiterate this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is using Bootstrap v3 with Bootstrap v4 example. Updating the code with v3 Navbar or the bootstrap version to v4 should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Bootstrap that way. Use `react-bootstrap` instead. Here's a link:

[React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

An example code:

```
const NavDropdownExample = React.createClass({
  handleSelect(eventKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`selected ${eventKey}`);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey="1" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        <NavItem eventKey="1" href="/home">NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey="2" title="Item">NavItem 2 content</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey="3" disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
        <NavDropdown eventKey="4" title="Dropdown" id="nav-dropdown">
          <MenuItem eventKey="4.1">Action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="4.2">Another action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="4.3">Something else here</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey="4.4">Separated link</MenuItem>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<NavDropdownExample />, mountNode);
```

Comment: I see this documented in the `create-react-app` guide, but I'd like to know why this is preferred. I find for readability, sticking to well-known conventions like using bootstrap in className is better. Also, when bootstrap updates, we can't be sure that the creators of react-bootstrap will keep it up to date.

Comment: From my experience, using className simply don't work. It's also interesting to have in mind that there is some JS related to collapsing things, like menus, and showing modals.